# Android Launcher app icon not updated to new icon after market update

Tags: android, launcher

I have provided an update for my application via Android market.
After new application installed from market, my app icon alone has not changed to the new app icon in the Android Launcher screen.

However, if the mobile restarted once, the new icon is reflected in Launcher screen too. It looks like my old app icon cached in Android Launcher.

What could be an issue? Is that a bug with Android or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe this is a bug (pre Android 3.0). I have experienced the same, however it does not happen on my tablet and Galaxy Nexus

Comment: This is still the issue even on Android 5.0.1. Shame on Google. The [related issue on the code Google site](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42921) is closed as `obsolete` without any explanations (as Google usually does).

Answer (score 19):

The app in the app launcher (drawer) should be updated, but the shortcuts won't be updated until the next refresh of the homescreen. There isn't much you can do that unfortunately, but the homescreen does refresh itself once in a while, so the new icon will eventually replace the old icon automatically.

Comment: same thing with the Settings - if you upgrade an app icon and then go into Settings, you may still find the old icon. The new icon surfaces once the phone is restarted or the Settings app is explicitly stopped.

Answer (score 3):

Same Problem !! did you check after clear cache or reboot your device

After clear caches my problem is Gone

> Try
>
> 1. Setting -> Apps -> All -> yourApp - > Clear Cache
> 2. if not updated Than Reboot Device

Check this link - [Android application name and icon doesn't change until phone is rebooted (after application update)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939552/android-application-name-and-icon-doesnt-change-until-phone-is-rebooted-after)

Answer (score 3):

Restarting the phone solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems and tried different approaches (one was trying to remove programatically the launcher screen's icon and the add the new one; I was able to add the new one but couldn't remove the old one; android:duplicate doesn't replace the old one only avoids to add the new icon and if trying to remove and I as far as I've researched so far  was removed starting with ICS).
But my conclusion is that there's an Android issue and you can find it posted here: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54546

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem, because of `roundIcon` configuration. So please make sure, you have updated both `icon` and `roundIcon`.

Android uses either of the icons based on the device configuration. Hence we should be defining both kinds of icons

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1#circular-icons

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me with action bar icons. In intelliJ, I had to explicitly rebuild the project for the icon change to take effect. It's worth mentionning that the faulty icon name remained the same (I was switching from holo light to holo dark)