# Android application name and icon doesn't change until phone is rebooted (after application update)

Tags: android

**Problem** : In the latest update of my Android application, the application name and logo have changed. However, when users update the application, the name and icon don't change until the phone is rebooted.

**Questions** : Is there anything I could do to enforce the change immediately? Or should I inform users somehow that a reboot is necessary? Or can I somehow force a reboot? Any other ideas?

Comment: Side Note: Reorder the app in application list should also refresh app icon and name, as an alternative to reboot.

Comment: The same can happen with the app name!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The icon is stored in cache, so the only ways to refresh it are to reboot the phone or to clean app cache then update.

Comment: Can this done by me in my code or can only the user do this? Should or can I inform the user of this either before or after the update, and how?

Comment: Rebooting doesn't works all the time. In my LG tablet, I tested it yesterday and today I'm still with the old icon, even though I rebooted it sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart your launcher in order to refresh the icon and name. For this, you may go to **Settings** -> **Applications** -> **Your-Installed-Launcher** -> **Force stop**. Once you land on home screen, your launcher will kick-in and refresh everything itself

Comment: Can this done by me in my code or can only the user do this? Should or can I inform the user of this either before or after the update, and how?

Comment: You cant affect other apps runt-time. So its something your users need to perform manually.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a common way to inform users about stuff like this before or after they update?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. +1 for the advice, although I think that from a users point of view its easier to tell them to reboot their phone then go through the process you mentioned.

Comment: yes, its just an alternate to show that restart is not a MUST :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works in the users but, I face this problem with the emulator. My solution is renaming the ic_launcher.png to something ic_launcher2.png. Since it automatically updates references, it is pretty fast.

Answer (score -1):

I resolve this issue by change the language to a differed one and back , this is working every time