# Android, Why launcher icon and other images never change when I update my images?

Tags: android, launcher, updating

I released one version of my application. For this version I had an image for launcher icon. For next version (update), I replaced this icon with other image.

My problem is when I update last version with new one, new launcher icon doesn't display and old one is still displaying.

However, if I clear data before uninstall and after that uninstall then by installing new version I can see new launcher image. The problem is I cannot ask all customers one by one please clear data and then uninstall before updating to new version.

What is the solution?

Comment: Can we see the `code` where you are replacing your different version application

What are you doing with the change of version number

Comment: Thanks raghav, I'm not replacing through code. I mean that I change image in rec/drawable folder. I change overther and refreshing, building and compiling in eclipse.

Comment: its because there are in emulator they have some previous cache stored in emulator/device 
you need to uninstall the application sometimes to see your changes

Comment: emulator? I don't care of emulator. This problem happens on real device.

Comment: if you really dont want this then you have to edit the code

Comment: @Hesam, have u found any solution? i also have this problem.

Comment: Same issue here, realdevices. Launcher's cache seems persistent.

Comment: more solutions here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939552/android-application-name-and-icon-doesnt-change-until-phone-is-rebooted-after

Answer (score 1):

I have changed launcher icons for my apps several times, and have no problems with it (user base is few millions users). You have nothing to do in your source code, just replace your `.png` file in `res` folder and rebuild your project.

Note: if you are building final `.apk` using some IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, etc.) do not forget to refresh and make a full clean of your project before building it.

Comment: Thanks deat Hit, You are right. But with one single APK if I update pre-installed app with new one, old icon will be displayed. However, if I remove application from device and install app with this APK file again, then new icon will be displayed. This is problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "pre-installed app"? Is your app beeing pre-installed on some Android devices within native firmware?

Comment: Oh no. I released first version of app in Play market. For second release, I just changed launcher icon and two image backgrounds. Then I upload it in Play market. Now, after upgrading app from version 1 to 2, launcher icon and one image is still same as before (just one image replaced correctly). But if i uninstall version 1 from device and install version 2 then everything is ok. If you still cannot get what i mean please forgive me my English is horrible :). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check you have mention the icon in the manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

I have the same issue when i was not added the icon in the application tag. but it got resolve after add the icon in the application tag

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as replacing the image, but sometimes it doesn't work on eclipse. I solved it just deleting the old icon launcher (all versions mdpi,hdpi...) and then pasting the new ones with a different name.

Maybe it is not your case, but it was my case, and it could be for another one.